# Oracle - find table on which a deadlock occurred

Tags: oracle, hibernate

A deadlock occurred in my Oracle DB. The deadlock (ORA-00060) occurs when I delete concurrently two entities from the same table. How can I find out, on which table the locks have been set?

What I did so far is:

1. I obtained a trace file that contains the deadlock graph, so the question number one is: Can I somehow identify the table on which the locks have been set using resource name from the deadlock graph? How? The resource name has following format: TM-000168D7-00000000-00000005-00000000
2. It seems that missing index on foreign key is the most common source of this kind of deadlocks, so I have checked if there are some missing indexes and couldn't find one. But still, the the schema is quite complex so I could overlook it.

Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: I was reading t/his somewhere  -  http://oracledbahub.com/2011/02/query-to-get-deadlocked-table-and-fired-query-during-deadlock

Comment: Have you found the column related to 000168D7? Is it has a foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many online resources to help you understand deadlocks.

"TM" is a transaction or DML enqueue (lock), so you probably have a transaction that runs longer than it should, before committing.

Here is a script to find your unindexed foreign keys:

```
select cc.owner, cc.table_name, cc.column_name, cc.position   
from dba_cons_columns cc
where 
 cc.owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM')
 and position is not null
minus
select i.index_owner, i.table_name, i.column_name, i.column_position
from dba_ind_columns i
where 
 i.index_owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM')
```